# Implementing environments the Heroku way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Heroku [advices against](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-to-a-custom-rails-environment) using the default Rails' way of creating custom environments: `config/environments/staging.rb`

Instead they suggest using [their config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Do I understand it correctly then, that to identify in which "environment" code is in I would set variables like the following:

```
heroku config:set CUSTOM_ENV=staging --remote my_staging_app
heroku config:set CUSTOM_ENV=production --remote my_production_app
```

And then in my code:

```
send_real_mail if ENV['CUSTOM_ENV'] == "production"
```

Comment: can you post heroku logs what error do you get?

Comment: I haven't done the implementation yet, I'm trying to get my head around the concept. So my question is "Is this how I would go about implementing environments the Heroku way?".